# Lock screen launch bar not launching app, shows different icon too

Tags: lock-screens, launcher, htc, nova-launcher

This is an HTC One with Android 4.3 and Nova Launcher Prime (This may be a Nova issue, not sure yet)

Since a picture is worth 1000 words, here is the pictures:

Dragging an icon "up" from the lock screen is supposed to unlock the phone and launch the app. This worked fine until I changed SMS apps

[image: The lock screen launcher]

Now when the phone is locked, it shows this funny little android icon instead of the Textra icon. Dragging the icon up unlocks the phone, but does not launch the app

[image: Once the phone is unlocked]

Once the phone is unlocked, the proper icon shows (With the music and browser icons swapped) and clicking the textra icon launches the app properly.

I'm going to contact the Nova developer with this as well, but was wondering if anyone had seen anything like this before.

**UPDATE

This now appears to be a bug or issue with Nova.

Tried something I should have tried before asking, but I will update with the solution anyway.

I dropped back to the default HTC Sense launcher and the Textra icon was not where it should be. I re-created the shortcut with the HTC launcher, then went back to Nova and got the proper icon and launch behavior.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the lock screen icons are configured separately from the home screen icons. If the lock screen shortcut is pointing to an app that's no longer installed, I'd expect it to show the icon you're seeing (the default app icon).

Try going into the lock screen's settings and setting the shortcut to the new app you want.

Comment: Did this a few times a couple of different ways

Answer (score 0):

I have Nova Launcher running on an HTC One 4.3 and no, it is not an issue with either Android or Nova Launcher. Just the old app taking revenge! (My attempt at humour, sorry)

## To fix this:

1. Go to Settings
2. Go to Apps
3. Go to Nova Launcher
4. Clear Defaults
5. Press Home and select HTC Sense (selecting *"only once"*)
   [doesnt the dock look familiar?!]
6. Change the dock icons to desired ones
7. Press home and select Nova Launcher (selecting *"always"*)
8. DONE!

## Reasoning

Any changes that you make to Nova Launcher or most launcher for that matter, like replace the music app shortcut with a calender app will not take place in your default HTC Sense Home Launcher (the default home launcher). So when your lock screen accesses the dock, it will display the icons only in the HTC Sense Home Launcher dock.

Now you said that you changed the SMS app. When you did so, you probably changed the shortcut in the Nova Launcher Dock Bar but didn't in the Home Launcher; thus the problem!

*Tip: You can use this to your advantage to use the **default dock** for handy apps like camera, phone and music for quick access only on your lock screen!